# How many cars do Chinese brands produce outside China?

Tags: data-request, china

Some Chinese car manufacturers have factories outside China. For example [FAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAW_Group) produces trucks in South Africa. How many cars do Chinese brands manufacture in factories outside China? Say for example in 2017 or 2018.

For example: Nearly six million vehicles are produced in Germany each year, and approximately 5.5 million are produced overseas by German brands.

Comment: Would you consider [Volvo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvo_Cars), a "Swedish marque" owned by the [Zhejiang Geely Holding Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geely) a Chinese brand or not? So given the usually multinational environment could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "Chinese companies".

Comment: @Giskard: I think both versions are equally interesting. However if I have to chose only one, then I chose the same applied to the German brands exemplified above, to make it easier to compare China with another country. I dont know which one is applied there but I suspect it is the "Skoda is Czech and not German" therefore "Volvo not Chinese"