# How many cars are made in China by Chinese brands?

Tags: data-request

From the 25+ million cars made annually in China, many of them are German, American or Japanese brands.

How many of the cars made inside China are actually Chinese brands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many cars do Chinese brands produce outside China?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/37761/how-many-cars-do-chinese-brands-produce-outside-china)

Comment: @1muflon1 One question is about the data in China, the other is outside of China. Granted, they could be merged, and also probably clarified.

Comment: @Giskard oh okay did not noticed that I will retract the close vote